# ARM M33 Undefined Instruction Fault

Tags: arm

I am using an STM32L5 MCU on a project (ARM M33 core).  The firmware consists of a bootloader and application.  After performing a remote firmware upgrade (via the bootloader), some of my devices did not come back online.  After placing a few on the debugger, I noticed that they were throwing an Undefined Instruction Hard Fault.

I would like to note that, given a set of identical devices (hardware and firmware) only a a few random devices suffer from this problem.  I also noted that, while stepping through the debugger, once the bootloader jumps into the application, many instructions from the application execute without issue.  However, eventually the invalid instruction fault is thrown on what (from the debugger and list file) is a valid instruction.

My first thought was that the firmware image (that just got flashed) was corrupted.  However, after reading back the data, I confirmed that it matched byte-for-byte to the file (which I know works) which I downloaded.

I then stepped to and through the problem code via the debugger (I got the PC address from the fault handler).  By manually stepping through the instructions, the fault never occurs.

I then started wondering if the branch from the bootloader to application firmware was causing some issue with the instruction cache/pipeline.  I added and ISB and DSB before the branch, which did not fix the issue.  Finally, I disabled the instruction cache.  Witch the cache disabled, no fault occurs.

My question is, has anyone experienced an issue like this before? To me this seems like the instruction cache is becoming "corrupted" somehow so that the core is reading an invalid instruction from the cache.  Is there any way I can keep the instruction cache enabled and prevent this issue from occurring?

For reference here is the source for the branch to the application:

```
//Jump to application
__set_MSP( intImage->image.stack );
::__DSB();
::__ISB();
intImage->image.reset_handler( );
```

Where `intImage` is just a pointer to a struct which is at address 0 of the application.  The first 32-bit value is the stack, the second 32-bit value is the address of the reset vector.

The assembly is:

```
  __ASM volatile ("MSR msp, %0" : : "r" (topOfMainStack) : );
 8002702:   f8d5 3200   ldr.w   r3, [r5, #512]  ; 0x200
 8002706:   f383 8808   msr MSP, r3
  __ASM volatile ("dsb 0xF":::"memory");
 800270a:   f3bf 8f4f   dsb sy
  __ASM volatile ("isb 0xF":::"memory");
 800270e:   f3bf 8f6f   isb sy
  intImage->image.reset_handler( );
 8002712:   f8d5 3204   ldr.w   r3, [r5, #516]  ; 0x204
 8002716:   4798        blx r3
```

Comment: are you exceeding the speed limits of flash or other components in the chip.  do you have the appropriate wait states, etc set?

Comment: and the value being loaded into r3?  address 8002712 plus 0x208 give or take.  exact addresses for these calls.

Comment: @old_timer I verified that I am setting the flash wait states and core voltage scaling to the correct values for the clock frequency I am using (110Mhz).

Comment: @old_timer I verified that, at the time the BLX instruction is executed, R3 contains the value 0x8046869.  0x8046868 is the address of the Reset_Handler function in the application.  Bit 0 is set to 1 to indicated that the Thumb instruction set shall be used.  So yes, everything checks out correctly.